# Is it relevant to run a Thread in Context Listner in J2EE?

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, daemon

I want to design a process which will always run in background. So I write a Thread class and write the process in infinite loop in run method. I know running a thread in J2EE not right practice. But any how I want continuous process in background. Is it right or what else I can do?

Comment: How about using a scheduled timer? Take a look at this: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html

Comment: @Robby : That is the ultimate solution if i will not able to implement threading. but Timers can be used in this application but not really made for Background Daemon thread. So is it any other better option. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no restriction that is documented. As long as you can control the threads (for example you do not create one every request) and you gracefully shut them down, my experience is that it does not create any issues.